# Center UL in parent and ignore other floating ULs

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I have a problem:

I'm building a wordpress site with Bootstrap.

I have a navbar with 3 menus: Left, Middle and Right.

Every UL is surrounded by an `div` like `navbar-menu-left` or `navbar-menu-right`.
The left and right `div`s are floated left or right.

Now I want to have the middle-menu in the middle or the `navbar`. If I center it with `text-align: center` in the `navbar-header div`, it's centered but if there's no right menu, it is centered between the left menu and the right side of the `navbar`. How can I center die middle menu in the parent `div` and not between the floating `div`s?

Margin doesn't work, the `navbar-menu-middle` is displayed with `display: inline block`. If i remove the `display: inline-block` it is next to the right menu. The order of the menus is:

`left`, `right`, `middle`

The images show what I mean:
Everything good (menus have nearly the same width):
[image]

But now: (right menu isn't there, may not be needed on some pages):
[image]
The problem is, that I don't know the width of the `ul`s..

Hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick would be to have width of all three menu-containers be 33%. and seting `text-align:left`,`text-align:center` and `text-align:right` to containers  Left, Middle and Right respectively.

Comment: Probably the best solution indeed, just use the column grid classes, e.g. `.col-xs-4` to create a layout and the text alignment classes, e.g. `.text-center`, to position the menu items.